# How overwrite safari blue outline for black?

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a input. And I set such CSS for it:

```
input:active,
input:focus {
  outline: 1px auto rgb(16, 16, 16) !important;
  outline-offset:0px;
}
```

But when I trying to check it by https://appetize.io/, my input stay with blue outline:

[image: screenshot of blue outline]

I expecting to get my input with black outline on focus.

```css
    input:active,
    input:focus {
      outline: 1px auto rgb(16, 16, 16) !important;
      outline-offset:0px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: I've added a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) so that others can test the CSS on their own instances of Safari (which, being a Windows user, I lack). You should consider adding this type of thing yourself on new questions to make it easier for answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could hide the outline and make your own focus/active style through a combination of border-color and/or box-shadow.

```
input:active,
input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgb(16, 16, 16);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.5);
}
```